# Usage of 'should have'

Tags: should, have

We know that [Should have + past participle] can mean something that would have been a good idea, but that you didn't do it. As in the following example-

Example: I should have studied harder but I didn't.

> .....They will be eligible to claim the allowance for three months during the period from start of lockdown on March 24 to December 31. *They **should have been** part of the scheme for two years during the period from April 1, 2018, to March 31, 2020, and should have contributed at least for 78 days from October 1, 2019, to March 31, 2020 and also in one of the other three six monthly contribution periods from April 1, 2018.* <sub>TNN</sub>

[image]

But in this paper cutting "should have" seems to have been used in different sense. Please clarify it.

Comment: The past participle of "be" is "been". Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I know it .... I mean to say In which sence "should have been" and" should have contributed " is used???Pls see the sentence marked with red line ...@Stockfish

Comment: Sir u didn't get my point ....or i am unable to make u understand... Pls see comment of GEdgar sir...Hope u will get what I mean to say...

Comment: This is the 'must have' sense. A very official register.

Comment: Thank you Edwin sir

Answer (score 1):

"Should have" can also refer to something you were assumed to do, without specifying whether you did it or not.

> How much did I spend on movies last year?  Well, a movie costs about $10, and I went to a movie about once a month, so I should have spent  about $120.

In this example, it does not mean spending money was a good idea, and it does not mean I didn't do it.

Comment: Thanks sir....Now I got it... Could u pls give some other example?? @GEdgar

Comment: But the use of "should have been" and "should have contributed" in the newspaper clipping suggests that these things, while they should have happened earlier, didn't. The paragraph highlights the plight of the labour force and says that these things should have taken place earlier, but they didn't. The "movie" example of GEdgar, while correct, could be misleading here.

Comment: @Stockfish No, these are the conditions the workers need to have met to claim the benefits. Nothing says they have failed to meet the conditions. Nothing.

Comment: Well, either of these versions could be true. What pumps so much force into your "nothings" ? They seem to be leaping out from the screen.

Comment: Thank you sir @Xanne

Answer (score 1):

The following is the sense of [*should*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should) that's being used in the article:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **4** —used in auxiliary function to express what is probable or expected
>     // with an early start, they *should* be here by noon

The following is a paraphrase of this sense, as used in the article:

> **It is likely** [they were] part of the scheme for two years during the period from April 1, 2018, to March 31, 2020, and **it is likely** [they] contributed at least for 78 days from October 1, 2019, to March 31, 2020 and also in one of the other three six monthly contribution periods from April 1, 2018.